# Heroku console weird date issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a cron task that runs once a day, using Heroku's Daily Cron addon. The cron takes values from yesterday's data and creates required objects with today's timestamp. But, I am facing unusual circumstances. This is from Heroku console :

```
>> Date.today
=> Thu, 25 Aug 2011
>> Date.yesterday
=> Thu, 25 Aug 2011
>> DateTime.now
=> Thu, 25 Aug 2011 23:31:42 -0700
```

The current time being 23:31, I thought of giving it a try later on. This is what I have now :

```
>> Date.today
=> Fri, 26 Aug 2011
>> Date.yesterday
=> Thu, 25 Aug 2011
>> DateTime.now
=> Fri, 26 Aug 2011 00:35:14 -0700
```

Any ideas why Date.today and Date.yesterday provide the same result. Is it due to the timezone or other certain settings ?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a bug to me, but you can set the timezone of heroku via heroku config:add TZ=Europe/Berlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date.today represents date according to your server time irrespective of the time zone that you have set.

Date.yesterday is  Time.now.in_time_zone - 1.day. It depends on Time.zone that we have set

This example should clarify it:

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014 > Time.now  => 2011-08-26 03:21:10 +0545`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :015 > Time.zone => (GMT+00:00) UTC`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :016 > Time.now.in_time_zone => Thu, 25 Aug 2011 21:36:40 UTC +00:00`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :018 > Date.yesterday => Wed, 24 Aug 2011`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :017 > Date.today => Fri, 26 Aug 2011`

Now,after setting time-zone as Kathmandu. Date.yesterday changes as expected but there is no change to Date.today

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :019 > Time.zone="Kathmandu" => "Kathmandu"`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :022 > Time.now.in_time_zone => Fri, 26 Aug 2011 03:55:28 NPT +05:45`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :020 > Date.yesterday=> Thu, 25 Aug 2011`

`ruby-1.9.2-p180 :021 > Date.today  => Fri, 26 Aug 2011`

Comment: hmm..seems to be the issue.. so,
Date.yesterday is Time.now.in_time_zone - 1.day

Answer (score 2):

Date.Today is the default method provided by ruby.
Date.Yesterday though is not a ruby method but is provided by Rails as part of its core extensions.

Date.Yesterday returns `Date.current.yesterday`

Date.Current as quoted from rails documentation,

> Returns Time.zone.today when Time.zone or config.time_zone are set,
>   otherwise just returns Date.today

It seems this is the reason why you are getting the same date for both the methods.

Comment: You contradict the first case of above example where no timezone is set. Date.current cannot be Date.today because Date.yesterday is shown to be Wed and not Thu. 
So, is the first case an instance where the Timezone is set or not ? I guess Timezone is set thr else it should hv been nil. Only then the two answers - yours and Abhaya's support each other.
Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's problaby a TimeZone issue.

I'm developing in Spring Boot and I'm using the code below in the main class:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
```

And when generate a Date, LocalDate, LocalDateTime or Instant use:

```
public static Instant getInstantNow() {
        Clock utcClock = Clock.systemUTC();
        return Instant.now(utcClock).minusSeconds(10800);//my local comparing to UTC in seg.
    }

    public static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTimeNow() {
        ZonedDateTime nowBrasil = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Brazil/East"));
        return LocalDateTime.from(nowBrasil);
    }

    public static LocalDate getLocalDateNow() {
        ZonedDateTime nowBrasil = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Brazil/East"));
        return LocalDate.from(nowBrasil);
    }
```

Comment: Java is not really relevant to an 8 year old Ruby on Rails 3 question. The issue was not understanding what timezone things were being displayed in / not using the correct timezone-aware functions (server timezone can differ from the app’s configured timezone).